# How can I split list of website

Tags: php, regex

I have list of site like this :

```
$list_website = "http://www.stackoverflow.com;http://www.yahoo.com
http://www.facebook.com
 http://www.youtube.com www.google.com";
```

I want some this like this

```
array("http://www.stackoverflow.com", 
      "http://www.yahoo.com", 
      "http://www.facebook.com", "http://www.youtube.com", 
      "www.google.com");
```

I tired with this :

```
$txt1 = explode(';\n ',$list_website);
```

But doesn't wotk.

Thanks advance !

Comment: If it's a variable you defined, why are there newlines in the string ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [preg_split](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.preg-split.php)

```
$list_website = preg_split("/[\n ;]+/", trim($list_website));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`preg_split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) with  `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY`, i.e.:

```
$list_website = "http://www.stackoverflow.com;http://www.yahoo.com
http://www.facebook.com
http://www.youtube.com www.google.com";

$arraySites = preg_split('/(;|\s+)/m', $list_website, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY) ;

print_r($arraySites);
```

**Output:**

```
(
    [0] => http://www.stackoverflow.com
    [1] => http://www.yahoo.com
    [2] => http://www.facebook.com
    [3] => http://www.youtube.com
    [4] => www.google.com
)
```

---

**`preg_split` explanation:**

```
-1
```

> A limit of -1, 0 or NULL means "no limit"

```
PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY
```

> If this flag is set, only non-empty pieces will be returned by
>   preg_split().

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/KEIYgW)</kbd>